# Puppet silently fails to restart service

Tags: puppet

The Docker daemon sometimes crashes on our puppet-managed servers.

Puppet is expected to bring it back if this should happen, but fails to do so, and I think I know why. From the debug logs I can see puppet is doing this:

```
rc-service docker status
rc-service docker start
```

Doing the same manually on a crashed Docker shows:

```
rc-service docker status; echo $? 
* status: crashed
32

rc-service docker start; echo $?
 * WARNING: docker has already been started
0
```

Looks like it worked, but the service is still not running:

```
rc-service docker status; echo $? 
* status: crashed
32
```

What I'd like Puppet to do:

```
rc-service docker restart
```

The Puppet configuration looks like this:

```
service { ['docker']: 
  ensure => 'running',  
  enable => true,  
  hasrestart => true,
}
```

How to configure Puppet to use **restart** in this situation?

Comment: Does OpenRC in fact distinguish "crashed" as a state separate from "not running", so that it is reasonable for some initscripts' `start` actions to fail to start a crashed service?  If so, then this should be raised as an issue against Puppet.  Otherwise, it reflects a flaw in Docker, and should probably be raised there.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the exact commands for start, stop, status, and restart with the corresponding attributes in the `service` resource: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/service.html#service-attributes. This is, however, going to become "hacky" since you are using a restart command for a start command, but it should technically not break anything.

```
service { 'docker':
  ensure => running,
  enable => true,
  start  => 'rc-service docker restart',
}
```

I recommend verifying your assumption that `rc-service docker restart` actually successfully restarts the docker service after it crashes before going down this route, otherwise this will not remedy your root cause.

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: Although this involves fooling Puppet into doing a restart when it wants to start I will likely use it - it worked, thanks!